# pickle not saving (or loading?) object list variable outside __init__

Tags: python, list, pickle

Python beginner question here. I'm trying to save and load objects using pickle in a text based game I'm making, and list variables are not loading as expected. This is the code I wrote to test the problem:

```
import pickle

class my_class(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
        self.y = [1,2,3]

    a = [4,5,6]
    b = 8

def save(object1):
    print("Game saved")
    pickle_out = open("saveobject1","wb")
    pickle.dump(object1, pickle_out)
    pickle_out.close()

def load():
    print("Loading......")
    pickle_in = open("saveobject1","rb")
    object1 = pickle.load(pickle_in)
    return object1

object1 = my_class(10)

print ("object1.x = " + str(object1.x))
print ("object1.y = " + str(object1.y))
print ("object1.a = " + str(object1.a))
print ("object1.b = " + str(object1.b))
print ("\n")

answer = input("Would you like to save (s) or load (l)?: ")

if answer == "s":
    save(object1)

object1.x = 20
object1.y[2] = 6
object1.a[2] = 12
object1.b = 16

if answer == "l":
    object1 = load()

print ("object1.x = " + str(object1.x))
print ("object1.y = " + str(object1.y))
print ("object1.a = " + str(object1.a))
print ("object1.b = " + str(object1.b))
print ("\n")
```

List variables within **init** save and load OK (y in this example) but list variables outside **init** do not (a in this example). However, non-list variables outside **init** do save and load. Thanks in advance for advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All variables within `__init__` are instance variables, and so will be saved. Both the list and non-list variables outside `__init__` are class variables, so won't be saved.

However, when you change `object1.b` that creates the instance variable `b` instead of setting the class variable, so it will be saved. However, when you modify `object1.a`, you are not reassigning it, just an element of it, so it is still an (unsaved) class variable.

If you want to save it, make it an instance variable or save the class variables separately.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, makes more sense now. The list I want to save in the game is the world map, it's a list of lists with 42 elements in total, so I suppose making it an instance variable is easier than saving it separately. Unless there is an easy way to save such a list that I don't know of?